# how can ı write this function without using loop ? (while,for) I can only use recursion

Tags: c, binary-tree, draw

```
    void draw(int x[max], int a, int bh) {
    int i;
    if(a<=max){
    if([root]!=-1)
        {
        if(
           draw(x,2*a+1,depth
           for(i=0;i<bi++)
        {
               printf("\t");
        }
           printf("%d\n",x[a]);
        if(b>0)
        {
           draw(x,2*a+2,b-1);
           }
       }
   }
```

}

how can I write this code without loop? (without for,while) 
I can only use recursion.

Comment: Yes. Any loop can be achieved using recursion rather than while/for

Comment: With respect to the title edit and body rip&replace, if you have violated your school's policy by asking the question then the ethical thing to do is to report yourself to the appropriate school authorities.  Be aware that the original question title and text are still accessible to those with sufficient privilege.  You could also consider consulting [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), but do note that none of the suggestions therein address the ethical issue (and some have their own ethical baggage).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're expected to avoid the loop used to create the indenting, but it can indeed be replace with recursion.

To find a recursive solution to printing N tabs, we asked ourselves: How can I define printing N tabs in terms of printing a different number of tabs?

Well, you can print N tabs by printing one tab, then printing N-1 tabs.

```
void print_indent(unsigned i) {
   if (!i)
      return;

   printf("\t");
   print_indent(i-1);
}

print_indent(depth);
```

---

In fact, any loop can be replaced with recursion.

We know we can eliminate [tail call recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) with a loop. By doing the process in reverse, we know that

```
while (cond()) {
   body();
}
```

can be written as

```
void recursive_loop() {
   if (!cond())
      return;

   body();
   recursive_loop();
)

recursive_loop();
```

We also know that

```
for (init(); cond(); post()) {
   body();
}
```

is just another way of writing

```
init();
while (cond()) {
   body();
   post();
}
```

so

```
for (int i=0; i<depth; ++i) {
   printf("\t");
}
```

can be written as

```
void print_indent(int depth, int i) {
   if (i >= depth) {
      return;

   printf("\t");
   ++i;
   print_indent(depth, i);
}

int i = 0;
print_indent(depth, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another recursion function for printing `\t`:

```
void print_rec (int i){
   if(i > 0) {
      printf("\t");
      print_rec(i-1);
   } else {
    return;
   }
}
```

then in your function:

```
// replace for loop by print_rec function
print_rec(depth);
```